# Running unit tests on solution can't find appsettings

Tags: nunit, resharper

I have multiple test projects under my solution, each with their own app.config, and when I use Resharper 8.2.1 and click "Run Unit Tests" on the solution in Visual Studio 2013, the individual test projects have trouble locating their app settings.  However, if I click "Run Unit Tests" on each single project, there is no issue.

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling `ReSharper | Options | Tools | Unit Testing | "Use separate AppDomain for each assembly with test"`